# cannot convert char to GluByte (How to use Reinterpreted_cast)

Tags: c++, opengl

I was given a piece of code to run a system test on my laptop so my professor can get a basic idea of what systems we're all running on (about to start an OpenGL course).  I'm pretty new to OpenGL and C++ (having primarily used Java in the past) and after spending ages trying to fix an issue with it not finding a correct lib file, I now get this error:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const GLubyte *' to 'const char *'
>   1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

I've taken this to mean I have to cast it, but again as I'm inexperienced in this language I don't know the correct format or proper way to do this, and researching it hasn't really helped since GL has updated, most responses I can find recommended using the updated glGetStringi, and others I've tried haven't worked.

If anyone would mind helping me I'd be very grateful, below is a copy of my code and the error is coming up on " p=glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glaux.h>

#define GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS              0x84E2
#define APIENTRYP APIENTRY *
#define PADDR(functype,funcname) (funcname = (functype) wglGetProcAddress( #funcname ))
#define GLAPI extern


typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGL) (void);
typedef GLboolean (APIENTRYP PFNGLISRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC) (GLuint);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC) (GLenum target, GLuint renderbuffer);
typedef GLboolean (APIENTRYP PFNGLISFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC) (GLuint framebuffer);
typedef void (APIENTRYP PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC) (GLenum target, GLuint framebuffer);

PFNGL glActiveTexture;
PFNGL glMultiTexCoord2f;
PFNGL glTexImage3D;
PFNGLISRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC glIsRenderbufferEXT;
PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC glBindRenderbufferEXT;
PFNGLISFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC glIsFramebufferEXT;
PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC glBindFramebufferEXT;


void main(int argc, char **argv){
 const char *p;
 GLint naux,nlights,maxtxsize,maxviewsize[2],maxtxunits;
 auxInitDisplayMode(AUX_SINGLE | AUX_RGBA);
 auxInitPosition(0,0,400,400);
 auxInitWindow(argv[0]);
 printf("OpenGL Version:  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION)); 
 printf("OpenGL Vendor :  %s\n", glGetString(GL_VENDOR)); 
 printf("OpenGL Renderer: %s\n", glGetString(GL_RENDERER)); 
 printf("\nGL Extensions Supported:\n\n");
 p=glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
 while(*p != 0){
  putchar(*p); if(*p == ' ')printf("\n");
  p++;
 }
 glGetIntegerv(GL_AUX_BUFFERS,&naux);
 printf("No of aux buffers %ld\n",naux);
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_LIGHTS,&nlights);
 printf("Max number of lights %ld\n",nlights);
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE,&maxtxsize);
 printf("Max texture size %ld\n",maxtxsize);
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS,&maxtxunits);
 printf("Max texture units %ld\n",maxtxunits);
 glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS,maxviewsize);
 printf("Max viewsize %ld %ld\n",maxviewsize[0],maxviewsize[1]);
 printf("\n");
 PADDR(PFNGL, glActiveTexture); printf("Active texture function ");
 if(glActiveTexture == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");
 PADDR(PFNGL, glMultiTexCoord2f); printf("MultiTex texture function ");
 if(glMultiTexCoord2f == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");
 PADDR(PFNGL, glTexImage3D); printf("TexImage3D texture function ");
 if(glTexImage3D == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");
 PADDR(PFNGLISRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC,glIsRenderbufferEXT); printf("IsRenderbuffer function ");
 if(glIsRenderbufferEXT == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");
 PADDR(PFNGLBINDRENDERBUFFEREXTPROC, glBindRenderbufferEXT); printf("BindRenderbuffer function ");
 if(glBindRenderbufferEXT == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");
 PADDR(PFNGLISFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC,glIsFramebufferEXT); printf("IsFramebuffer function ");
 if(glIsFramebufferEXT == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");
 PADDR(PFNGLBINDFRAMEBUFFEREXTPROC, glBindFramebufferEXT); printf("BindFramebuffer function ");
 if(glBindFramebufferEXT == NULL)printf("Not found\n"); else printf("OK\n");


 //getch();
 glFlush();
}
```

Comment: C does not have `reinterpret_cast`. And the signature of `main` is wrong - your compiler should complain.

Comment: `GLubyte` is defined as `unsigned char`, so have you tried `const unsigned char *p` or `const GLubyte *p`?

Comment: @BDL I tried changing it to GLubyte before (and just tried the unsigned change), it gives me a new error though for an unresolved external symbol for all the auxInit statements (auxInitDisplayMode, Position and Window).

Comment: The conversion thing is a compiler error. An unresolved external is a linker error. Since linking comes after compiling, you will have to fix the casting first and then fix the unresolved external. For linking: Do you link against the appropriate library (glaux.lib)?

Comment: @BDL, I just added the glaux library into a folder inside my project and linked it again (it was previously on my C: drive but it wasn't recognizing it), doing that and changing the char to type Glubyte has solved my issue :D Thank you so much for your help (and explaining what causes those errors)